# Use and meaning of "in" in an if statement?

Tags: python

In an example from Zed Shaw's *Learn Python the Hard Way*, one of the exercises displays the following code:

```
next = raw_input("> ")
if "0" in next or "1" in next:
    how_much = int(next)
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of `in` in this statement. I'm used to using `if` statements, such as in javascript, where the syntax is something like:

```
var = 5;
if (var > 3) {
    //code  to be executed
}
```

Is this `if` / `in` statement (in python) the same as `if()` in javascript?

Finding an answer to this has been tricky because the `in` is such a short string to narrow down an answer via search engine, and I don't know the proper name for its operation.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Comment: It may also help to search Google using operators-- for example, `python "in" operator` gives exactly what you would need in its first few results.

Comment: On recent Pythons (2.6+), you should not use `next` as a variable name. You will overwrite the built-in function [next](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next)

Comment: what do you think it might mean if i say `if "whatever" in some_list:`

Comment: @abarnert I didn't, I just assumed, based on the function of the code, that it was somehow connected to an 'if' statement. I may be used to javascript but I am in no way an expert in either of these languages

Comment: @Scherf: Well, it's "connected" to an `if` statement in the same way that `>` or any other operator is… and the same way as in JavaScript.

Comment: Which is essentially what I was asking about. I understood what its function was but not really what it meant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It depends on what `next` is.

If it's a string (as in your example), then `in` checks for substrings.

```
>>> "in" in "indigo"
True
>>> "in" in "violet"
False
>>> "0" in "10"
True
>>> "1" in "10"
True
```

If it's a different kind of iterable (list, tuple, set, dictionary...), then `in` checks for membership.

```
>>> "in" in ["in", "out"]
True
>>> "in" in ["indigo", "violet"]
False
```

In a dictionary, membership is seen as "being one of the keys":

```
>>> "in" in {"in": "out"}
True
>>> "in" in {"out": "in"}
False
```

Comment: or a custom classes `__contains__`  method ;P

Comment: Would you have to write a lambda function to change `"in" in ["indigo", "violet"]` into True for matching the "in" in "indigo"?

Comment: @sinekonata: `any('in' in item for item in ['indigo', 'violet'])` would be sufficient for this.

Answer (score 28):

Using `a in b` is simply translates to `b.__contains__(a)`, which *should* return if b includes a or not.

But, your example looks a little weird, it takes an input from user and assigns its integer value to `how_much` variable **if the input contains `"0"` or `"1"`**.

Comment: "If the input contains 1 or 2"; why 1 or 2, and not 1 or 0? And for my own sake 'contains' literally means if the string has either number in it, then the expression is true?

Comment: My mistake, I misread those, of course it should be 1 or 0. Actually, contains checks(for strings), if given string is a substring(as others mentioned). There is two calls there: `if next.__contains__("0") or next.__contains__("1"):`.

Comment: +1: This answer complemenents the accepted one very well. For advanced users, it's better to be told about the implementation details than how to use the implementation.

Answer (score 15):

Since you claim to be used to JavaScript:

The Python [`in`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) operator is similar to the JavaScript [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

Here's some JavaScript:

```
var d = {1: 2, 3: 4};
if (1 in d) {
    alert('true!');
}
```

And the equivalent Python:

```
d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
if 1 in d:
    print('true!')
```

With objects/dicts, they're nearly identical, both checking whether `1` is a key of the object/dict. The big difference, of course, is that JavaScript is sloppily-typed, so `'1' in d` would be just as true.

With arrays/lists, they're very different. A JS array is an object, and its indexes are the keys, so `1 in [3, 4, 5]` will be `true`. A Python list is completely different from a dict, and its `in` operator checks the *values*, not the *indexes*, which tends to be more useful. And Python extends this behavior to all iterables.

With strings, they're even more different. A JS string isn't an object, so you will get a `TypeError`. But a Python `str` or `unicode` will check whether the other operand is a *substring*. (This means `1 in '123'` is illegal, because `1` can't be a substring of anything, but `'1' in '123'` is true.)

With objects as objects, in JS there is of course no distinction, but in Python, objects are instances of classes, not dicts. So, in JS, `1 in d` will be true for an object if it has a member or method named `'1'`, but in Python, it's up to your class what it means—Python will call `d.__contains__(1)`, then, if that fails, it tries to use your object as an utterable (by calling its `__iter__`, and, if that fails, by trying to index it with integers starting from `0`).

Also, note that JS's `in`, because it's actually checking for object membership, does the usual JS method-resolution-order search, while Python's `in`, because it's checking for keys of a dict, members of a sequence, etc., does no such thing. So, technically, it's probably a bit closer to the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method than the `in` operator.

Answer (score 4):

You are used to using the javascript `if`, and I assume you know how it works.

`in` is a *Pythonic* way of implementing iteration. It's supposed to be easier for non-programmatic thinkers to adopt, but that can sometimes make it harder for programmatic thinkers, ironically.

When you say `if x in y`, you are literally saying:

"if `x` is in `y`", which assumes that `y` has an index. In that `if` statement then, each object at each index in `y` is checked against the condition.

Similarly,

`for x in y`

iterates through `x`'s in `y`, where `y` is that indexable set of items.

Think of the `if` situation this way (pseudo-code):

```
for i in next:
    if i == "0" || i == "1":
        how_much = int(next)
```

It takes care of the iteration over `next` for you.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe these examples will help illustrate what `in` does. It basically translate to `Is this item in this other item?`

```
listOfNums = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 45, 'j' ]

>>> 3 in listOfNums:
>>> True

>>> 'j' in listOfNums:
>>> True

>>> 66 in listOfNums:
>>> False
```

Answer (score 2):

the reserved word "in" is used to look inside an object that can be iterated over.

```
list_obj = ['a', 'b', 'c']
tuple_obj = ('a', 1, 2.0)
dict_obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2.0}
obj_to_find = 'c'
if obj_to_find in list_obj:
    print('Object {0} is in {1}'.format(obj_to_find, list_obj))
obj_to_find = 2.0
if obj_to_find in tuple_obj:
    print('Object {0} is in {1}'.format(obj_to_find, tuple_obj))
obj_to_find = 'b'
if obj_to_find in dict_obj:
    print('Object {0} is in {1}'.format(obj_to_find, dict_obj))
```

Output:

```
Object c is in ['a', 'b', 'c']
Object 2.0 is in ('a', 1, 2.0)
Object b is in {'a': 1, 'b': 2.0}
```

However

```
cannot_iterate_over = 5.5
obj_to_find = 5.5
if obj_to_find in cannot_iterate_over:
    print('Object {0} is in {1}'.format(obj_to_find, cannot_iterate_over))
```

will throw

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/jgranger/workspace/sandbox/src/csv_file_creator.py", line 43, in <module>
if obj_to_find in cannot_iterate_over:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

In your case, raw_input("> ") returns iterable object or it will throw TypeError

Comment: [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) is guaranteed to return a `str`, which is iterable, so you don't need to guess whether it's returning an iterable object.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a very late answer. 
*in* operator checks for memberships. That is, it checks if its left operand is a member of its right operand.  In this case, raw_input() returns an *str* object of what is supplied by the user at the standard input.  So, the *if* condition checks whether the input contains substrings "0" or "1". Considering the typecasting (*int()*) in the following line, the *if* condition essentially checks if the input contains digits 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here `raw_input` is `string`, so if you wanted to check, `if var>3` then you should convert next to double, ie `float(next)` and do as you would do `if float(next)>3`:, but in most cases