# # Error: TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable #

Tags: python, maya

first post! I am fairly new to python and trying to improve, any help would be greatly appreciated! I've looked through other posts with similar questions still cant seem to get around this issue.

This is the error I receive, which happens on **line 5:**

```
    # Error: TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable #
```

This is my code:

```
userInput = cmds.textFieldGrp(searchText, query = True, text=True)
path = "D:\somefolder"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if (userInput in file.endswith('.ma')):
            print file
        else:
            break
            print "No files containing %s" (userInput)
```

Basically, I am trying to search for files in a directory based off keywords a user types in.

Looking forward to hearing from anyone, thank you!

Comment: Try debugging it using print yourself

Comment: The error you are currently getting is due to `userInput in file.endswith('.ma')`. That line is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: what do you mean by `file.endswith('.ma')` are you trying to check if file is of extention `.ma` or the file ends with text `file.endswith('.ma')`. If it later then you have to `open` and `read` the file

Comment: `file.endswith('.ma')` returns `True` if the file ends with '.ma' what you're doing is like: `if 'hello' in True:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that you are trying to get only the files that ends with `.ma` and filename containing the queryterm try example below and see if this helps

```
userInput = cmds.textFieldGrp(searchText, query = True, text=True)
path = "D:\somefolder"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if ((userInput in file) and file.endswith('.ma')):
            print file
        else:
            break
            print "No files containing %s" (userInput)
```

Comment: Thank you! Having it check with the "in" "and" worked out. Greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are currently getting is due to

```
userInput in file.endswith('.ma')
```

That line is not doing what you think it is doing.

`file.endswith('.ma')` returns a `bool`. The error is telling you that you are trying to *iterate* over bool. The `in` statement checks for *membership* in an iterable. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19775766/1832539) answer for more information on how `in` works.

Here is a separate demo to show you how the error is reproduced:

```
>>> 's' in False:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

Here is a working example:

```
>>> 's' in 'this will return true'
True
```

Comment: This information was also very helpful in understanding what was going on, thank you!