# Using function to select from list

Tags: python

Im learning python and i want to have this function "checkusername" check if the user is within a user list. but it dosent seem to check the list.

```
userlist = ["mint"]
ilogin = " "
ipass = " "

def displayWelcome():
    print "Welcome to Mints Server"
    print " "

def getUserLogin():
    return raw_input("Please enter in your login id: ")
def getUserPass():
    return raw_input("Please enter in your login password: ")
def displaylogincred(ID,password):
    print "ID: " + ID
    print "Pass" + password
def checkUsername(user):
    global userlist
    if user == userlist:
        return "Login Successful"
    else:
        return "Login Incorrect"

displayWelcome()
ilogin = getUserLogin()
ipass = getUserPass()
print checkUsername(ilogin)
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are doing in this line:

```
if user == userlist:
```

Is checking whether or not `user` and `userlist` are equal. This is not what you want. You want to check if a value equal to `user` is inside `userlist`, not whether or not `user` is the same as the entire `userlist`.

To check if a list contains a specific value, you use [`in`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775692/use-and-meaning-of-in-in-an-if-statement):

```
if user in userlist:
    return "Login Successful"
else:
    return "Login Incorrect"
```

Note that the `global userlist` you have before your `if` is completely unnecessary. `userlist` is not declared in any function or class so it is already accessible everywhere in your module.

Comment: To clarify, the double equals `==` checks to see if `user` is equivalent to `userlist` and the keyword `in` iterates through the collection and returns `True` as soon as an instance within the collection `userlist` is equivalent to `user`