# if in statement in python reverse

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm having a bit trouble here..

I'm kinda familiar with this the if x in xyz statement, I also got some good info from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775692/use-and-meaning-of-in-in-an-if-statement).
So from the answer I understand what it does.. But I need it in reverse..

Like this:
So I understand this concept:

```
text = "This whole sentence is text"
if text in ['whole', 'sentence']
   do something
```

But i actually need to check if some of the words are in the sentence instead of the upper..

Can I just do it like this:

```
text = "This whole sentence is text"
if ['whole', 'sentence'] in text
  do something
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

**TL;DR**

Keep in mind that the `text` variable is coming from somewhere else and I can't really change it easily. 
My google assistant is giving the `text` variable back from what it heard, and I want to be able to have it do actions without having to say a full literal sentence, so normally it looks like this:

```
text = event.args['text'].lower()
if text == 'power off':
   assistant.stop_conversation()
   power_off_pi()
```

So it checks the whole sentence, I just want to be able to let it check for certain words in the sentence.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if text in ['whole', 'sentence']` will always be false, because `text` is not set to `'whole'` or `'sentence'`.

Comment: you mean `any(x in text for x in ['whole', 'sentence'])`