# Python word translator code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to fully understand this code. Help will be much appreciated. This is a code where when I input a phrase or a word, the result will give me the same thing except for every vowel changed into a "g"

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation += "g"
        else:
            translation += letter
    return translation
```

I can figure everything else out except, the part where translation +="g"
I don't get how that will switch every vowel into a "g"
So, I would love for someone to walk me through this code, step by step please.
Thank you.

Comment: This is loading the translation into a new variable called `translation`. By looping through every character, it keeps adding either the "g" or the consonant, so the final result is the one you describe.

Comment: It adds each letter to `translation`, except if that letter is present in `"AEIOUaeiou"`, in which case it adds a `"g"` instead.

Comment: For future reference, running your code through a debugger is usually a lot clearer and more efficient than asking how it works on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you check [this post on the use of 'in' statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775692/use-and-meaning-of-in-in-an-if-statement). In general `in` can be applied to any kind of iterable, in the case of strings, `s1 in s2` will return `True` if `s1` is a sub string of `s2`. Because the loop only iterates over single characters, it will add a 'g' to the result, every time the character is a sub string of 'AEIOUaeiou'.