# How does the "in" keyword in python work ? Is there a faster way?

Tags: python

I am a programming newbie and I was playing with some big data (yelp dataset 6m+ reviews) and for a simple example I wanted to try to find a certain word in a text so basically i tried to for loop through all this data and find a certain word in these reviews and before getting triggered I know that this is the worst way of doing that but then I used nltk to preprocess the data, put the reviews in a list and check for the word inside this list using the "in" keyword and it was much faster so my question is what makes the "in" keyword faster ? And is there an even faster way other than improving the preprocessing part ?

Edit 1(here is an example code):

First I tokenize the review e.x "This place is good" becomes ["This","place","is","good"]

```
contents = word_tokenize(data[u'text'])
```

Then I check if a certain string is in this list

```
if(contents[i] in list_of_targeted_words): return 1
```

This appeared to be faster than using for loop

```
if(contents[i] == list_of_targeted_words[j]): return 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you understand how some code works, we need to first see the code. Please show us a short example that illustrates what you are asking about and we can help from there.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775692/use-and-meaning-of-in-in-an-if-statement Note that as this link explains, `in` works differently for different types of data.

Comment: It's not searching within the reviews but it's comparing the word with the whole reviews that are stored in the list. The internal workings of `a in b` depend very much on `type(b)`. For your list it comes down to roughly `any(a == x for x in b)`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added a sample code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in` itself is not faster; it's just the public face of the `__contains__` method that a class can define. `list.__contains__` is an O(n) operation because it has to walk through the entire list looking for a match.

```
# a in my_list
for x in my_list:
    if x == a:
        return True
return False
```

`dict.__contains__` is fast because it just needs to perform the O(1) lookup in a `dict` value.

```
# a in my_dict
try:
     my_dict[a]
     return True
 except KeyError:
     return False
```

Other classes can define `__contains__` as needed. Consider a class representing a binary search tree:

```
class BST:
    # You should be able to infer enough of the structure of the tree
    # from this definition.
    def __contains__(self, x):
        node = self.root
        while node is not None:
            if node.value == x:
                return True
            elif node.value < x:
                node = node.right
            else:
                node = node.left
        return False
```

Most importantly, it doesn't do an O(n) traversal of the entire tree looking for `x`; instead, it does a O(lg n) walk down from the root.

Comment: I think I can try the dict._contains_ method and check the differences, thank you for your clarification

Comment: What do you mean "try"? Either you have a `dict` or you don't; you can't apply `dict.__contains__` to an object that isn't a `dict`.

Comment: Well I am thinking to create the dictionary using the reviews first instead of creating a list

Comment: Note I am registering this as an answer because when I used a dictionary to search instead a list the code is much faster now thanks for the help ! If anyone is having any similar problem please let me know I will share the code with you.