# Using Another File As A Variable/Data source

Tags: python-3.x

I have written some code for a system, I have imported another file which stores all the information for login details. But when I go to test it and try to login it keeps coming up with "INCORRECT". Both of the code files are attached.

I have tried changing the names of the files, variables and changing the login details but it still doesn't work.

```
from database import user_data, pasw_data, no_file

name = user_data
code = pasw_data

def  user_check():
    user = input("USERNAME >>")
    if user == name:
        pasw_check()

    else:
        print("INCORRECT")

def pasw_check():
    pasw = input("PASSWORD >>")
    if pasw == code:
        print("ACCESS GRANTED")
user_check()
```

This is the file, which stores all the login info, named database.py

```
user_data = ["123"]
pasw_data = ["python"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking a *string* (`user`) and a *list* (`user_data`) for *equality*. They aren't equal at all. The list just happens to *contain* a string that's equal to your query. You should use [`in` to search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775692/use-and-meaning-of-in-in-an-if-statement) lists (and strings, dictionaries, tuples, etc) for data:

```
if user in user_data:
    print("I'm in!")
```

Comment: thanks for replying so quick, this helped me alot, it works perfect thanks!