# Click on a specific email from gmail inbox Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, gmail

Im trying to get an specific email from a gmail address (or subject).
Im using selenium because can't use imaplib for this gmail account.
Im stck here:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys('MYEMAIL')
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('PSWRD')
driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()

time.sleep(15)

email = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.xT>div.y6")

for emailsub in email:    
     if "someone@gmail.com" in emailsub:   #Error line
     emailsub.click()
     break
```

> Error: argument of type 'WebElement' is not iterable

Idk why I'm using `find_element`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your for is loop being done correctly and they way you call `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector` is fine. Inside of your for loop you are dealing with INDIVIDUAL instances of `WebElement`. The error you get is due to the use of the `in` statement, I would check [this post on using IN in a IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775692/use-and-meaning-of-in-in-an-if-statement) and furter understand what you are looking for in your in statement.

I suspect plainly iterating over the `WebElement` class is throwing this error, and you need to further define what the `in' applies to.