# what syntax i mine missing here please

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
mersenne_list = [mersenne_number(p) for p in the list_prime]
                                                          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

i entered the above code and it gave me this error, which syntax is missing, please

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `in the` to just `in`

```py
mersenne_list = [mersenne_number(p) for p in list_prime]
```

you can read more about `in` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775692/use-and-meaning-of-in-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `the`:

```
mersenne_list = [mersenne_number(p) for p in list_prime]
```

Python saw two names separated by a space which is invalid syntax.